# jackrabbit java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, jackrabbit

Who met this issue about jackrabbit? The trace follows:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>           at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.FieldNames.createNamedValue(FieldNames.java:141)
>           at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.NodeIndexer.createFieldWithoutNorms(NodeIndexer.java:539)
>           at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.NodeIndexer.addStringValue(NodeIndexer.java:754)
>           at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.NodeIndexer.addValue(NodeIndexer.java:376)
>           at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.NodeIndexer.createDoc(NodeIndexer.java:259)
>           at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex.createDocument(SearchIndex.java:1208)
>           at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex.updateNodes(SearchIndex.java:657)
>           at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.SearchManager.onEvent(SearchManager.java:408)
>           at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.observation.EventConsumer.consumeEvents(EventConsumer.java:248)
>           at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.observation.ObservationDispatcher.dispatchEvents(ObservationDispatcher.java:214)
>           at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.observation.EventStateCollection.dispatch(EventStateCollection.java:475)
>           at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.SharedItemStateManager$Update.end(SharedItemStateManager.java:801)
>           at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.SharedItemStateManager.update(SharedItemStateManager.java:1492)
>           at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.LocalItemStateManager.update(LocalItemStateManager.java:400)
>           at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.XAItemStateManager.update(XAItemStateManager.java:354)
>           at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.LocalItemStateManager.update(LocalItemStateManager.java:375)
>           at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.SessionItemStateManager.update(SessionItemStateManager.java:275)
>           at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.ItemSaveOperation.perform(ItemSaveOperation.java:258)
>           at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.session.SessionState.perform(SessionState.java:216)
>           at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.ItemImpl.perform(ItemImpl.java:91)
>           at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.ItemImpl.save(ItemImpl.java:329)
>           at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.session.SessionSaveOperation.perform(SessionSaveOperation.java:64)
>           at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.session.SessionState.perform(SessionState.java:216)
>           at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.SessionImpl.perform(SessionImpl.java:361)
>           at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:812)
>           at org.apache.jackrabbit.server.remoting.davex.JcrRemotingServlet.processDiff(JcrRemotingServlet.java:525)
>           at org.apache.jackrabbit.server.remoting.davex.JcrRemotingServlet.doPost(JcrRemotingServlet.java:398)
>           at org.apache.jackrabbit.webdav.server.AbstractWebdavServlet.execute(AbstractWebdavServlet.java:326)
>           at org.apache.jackrabbit.webdav.server.AbstractWebdavServlet.service(AbstractWebdavServlet.java:263)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)

Sometimes it will throw:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deal with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error (64MB heap size)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error-64mb-heap)

Answer (score 1):

It means, that there is not enough heap space to execute the program. You can try to specify more heap space when you start the JVM, for example

```
java -Xmx1G ...
```

will specify 1 GB heap space.

The option to set the heap space may vary with the JVM you use.